# Efficient overwriting of specific tensor elements

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a square, $n\times n$ rank 2 tensor `x`, a length $m$ list `p` of (distinct) positions in it, and a length $m$ list `y` of new values to update those positions. This serves to recreate the situation:

```
n = 100;
m = 10;
x = RandomReal[{0,1},{n,n}];
p = Transpose[{RandomSample[Range[n], m], RandomSample[Range[n], m]}];
y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, m];
```

What is the **most efficient**  way of overwriting positions `p` of `x` with the values of `y`?

Something that *would look* like `Extract[x,p] = y`, which isn't possible; or like `Part[x,p] = y` which only works like that if `x`, `p` and `y` are rank 1.

Comment: `ReplacePart[x, Thread[p -> y]]` or `ReplacePart[x, AssociationThread[p, y]]` could be neat candidates.

Comment: Thanks @BenIzd! It does achieve the right result. I did some efficiency testing with rank 1 tensors (to be able to compare with Part), and for my application ($n=3600$, $m=900$) they are about a factor 150 to 200 slower than Part. If I can't find something more or less as fast as Part, I may get around my problem by converting by rank 2 lists into properly ordered rank 1 lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we don't have a feature to change multiple assignment in more than 1-D data efficiently. Even though it's pretty simple and straight forward since Mathematica stores data in row-major format consecutively in memory.

To get the best performance, we could implement such algorithm in a low-level language to leverage the LibraryLink power. Which for this case, I chose Rust and you can find the library in [this repository](https://github.com/ben-izd/ReplacePartND).

#### Example

```
Block[{x = Range[10]},
 ReplacePartNDInPlace[x, {{2}, {5}, {10}}, {-1, -2, -3}];
 x
 ]

(* Out: {1, -1, 3, 4, -2, 6, 7, 8, 9, -3} *)
```

For your case (with n=3600, m=900):

```
n = 3600;
m = 900;
x = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
p = Transpose[{RandomSample[Range[n], m], 
    RandomSample[Range[n], m]}];
y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, m];
```

Simple built-in solution (Note that this solution unlike others will generate an output, while others will manipulate in place):

```
r1 = ReplacePart[x, Thread[p -> y]]; // 
  MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0262173, 104235400} *)
```

The solution:

```
Block[{},
  r2 = x;
    ReplacePartNDInPlace[r2, p, y]; // MaxMemoryUsed // 
   AbsoluteTiming
  ] // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0000627, {0.000058, 64}} *)
```

Another built-in solution with flatting the data (2D data):

```
Block[{xf = Flatten[x], temp = Dimensions[x], pt = p},
   temp[[-1]] = 1;
   pt[[All, 1]] -= 1;
   Print[AbsoluteTiming[xf[[pt . temp]] = y;]];
   r3 = ArrayReshape[xf, Dimensions[x]];
   ] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0009897,Null} *)
(* Out: {0.0506292, 207375864} *)
```

```
r1 === r2

(* Out: True *)


r1 === r3

(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for writing that library!